# Postman file and json returns 415 even with Content-Type Header .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, postman

I am using postman to test my .net core API, when i am trying to post data via postman form-data this returns a 415 even if i set the Content-Type header to application/json as the common solution for this issue appears to be online.
If i fire the request without any files via the raw postman option and set the content type as JSON(application/json) this request reaches the API successfully.

Here is how my API looks:

```
 [HttpPost("{organization}")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Asset asset, string organization)
    {
       //Api body
       //Get files from request
       Task uploadBlob = BlobFunctions.UploadBlobAsync(_blobContainer,Request.Form.Files[0]);
    }
```

And here is how the failed postman request looks like
[image]

and the header for that request

[image]

What else am i missing for this to work?

**Small update**

This works fine if i remove `[FromBody]Asset asset` and just pass the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [FromForm] attribute instead of the [FromBody] attribute:

```
 [HttpPost("{organization}")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromForm] string asset, string organization, IFormFile fileToPost)
    {
       //Api body
       Asset asset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Asset>(asset);
       //Get files from request
       Task uploadBlob = BlobFunctions.UploadBlobAsync(_blobContainer, fileToPost);
    }
```

I can't say for sure, but my guess is that in postman, since you're making a form-data request, your content-type would end up being "multipart/form-data" (if you debug the request when it is being processed, you can see that the content type changes to multipart even though you set it to application/json).

But in your Controller's POST action you specify that you expect an Asset object from the body (which expects a JSON object by default). So you get a 415 since your request's content type is multipart while your API expects application/json because you used the [FromBody] attribute.

Comment: Very good thanks for the explanation, it makes perfect sense. I have checked it and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for some weird reason I was not allowed to pass any of them as a variable of my controller but it works if I retrieve both from the `Request`.

```
 if (!Request.Form.ContainsKey("asset"))
 {
    return BadRequest("Asset cannot be empty");
 }
 Asset asset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Asset>(Request.Form.First(a => a.Key == "asset").Value);
```

and for the file

```
var file = equest.Form.Files[0]
```

Not sure why this is the case and would appreciate if someone could explain this to me but this seems to solve my issue.